"Trouble Starting XAMPP Download on Windows: Need Assistance"
I went to the XAMPP website and clicked on 'Download XAMPP for Windows.' I tried my best to download it but the download didn't start. I have downloaded many other software programs before, and the download usually starts automatically after clicking the download button, but in the case of XAMPP it doesn't start. Can anyone help solve my problem? Thanks in advance.
I am trying to download xamp for wndows but it did not work and i expect that someone will help me in downloading xamp.
